# Как отслеживаются изменения при стратегии OnPush для элементов формы [formControl]?

Tags: angular

Как отслеживаются изменения при стратегии `OnPush` для input элементов с директивой formControl. Где создается обработчик 'input' который вызывает `markForCheck`?

Comment: Приведите пример текстом, а не по ссылке.

Comment: @вася пример текстом привести не смогу, могу перефразировать вопрос. Как отслеживаются изменения при стратегии OnPush  для input элементов с директивой formControl. Где создается обработчик 'input' который вызывает markForCheck?

Comment: Все изменения и дополнения вносите в сам вопрос с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1144335/edit)

Comment: В каком плане как отслеживаются изменения? Какие изменения? `formControl` как и другие директивы вообще не используют `ChangeDetectorRef`. Буду краток - вопрос непонятен, хотя может это я такой педант =)